MathQuill hardware keyboard input rather than virtual keyboard
I am creating an angular application that using MathQuill for math equations input. I am using virtual keyboard by creating html buttons and button click events to pass input to MathQuill. I want to know if there is a way possible to use physical keyboard input to MathQuill. Here is my current code. Help me get input from physical keyboard rather than virtual one.
<div id="math-field" class="input"></div>



ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mathField = document.getElementById('math-field');
    var latexSpan = document.getElementById('latex')!;
    this.MQ = (window as any).MathQuill.getInterface(2);
    var mathField = this.MQ.MathField(this.mathField, {
      substituteTextarea: () => {
        return document.getElementById('substitue-id');
      },
      spaceBehavesLikeTab: true,
      handlers: {
        edit: function () {
          // useful event handlers
          latexSpan.textContent = mathField.latex(); // simple API
          mathField.focus()
        },
      },
    });
  }

